# How to find the topology of this subbase generated?

Tags: general-topology

I want to find topologies which uses this set as a subbase.
two different questions says

1. $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$  and $\mathcal S =\{\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{d\}\}$
2. $\{[x,x+1]\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$

In the first : when we take finite intersection of $\mathcal S$

we got

$B=\{\emptyset,X,\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{d\},\{b\}\}$ as a base

What produces (arbitrary union)

$\tau =\{\emptyset,X,\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{d\},\{b\},\{a,b,c\},\{a,b,d\},\{b,c,d\}\}$

For the second one: base $B= \{[x,x+1]\mid x\in \Bbb R\}\cup \{\Bbb R,\emptyset \}$

$\tau= \{[x,y]\mid x,y\in\Bbb R\}\cup \{\emptyset \}$

Is this approach correct? And also I'm not sure presentation of topology and base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first seems quite correct.  As to the second, what is the intersection of $[x-1,x]$ and $[x,x+1]$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$? You might want to grow your base somewhat.

The result will be quite a familiar topology, I think.

Comment: isnt that just $x\in R$ ? if we take x=y doesnt $\tau $ cover that intersections?

Comment: Yes, it's $\{x\}$, more precisely. Yes, we can also take $x = y$ to get the same set. In either case, the base has all singletons. My argument also works with the smaller subbase of all sets of the form $[x,y]$ with $x < y$.